# Is there an emotion speech detection - accurate classifier or large dataBase available publicly?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, audio

I am practicing machine learning and would like to explore more precise functionality with emotion recognition in speech.

I am looking for a ranked datatset or a trained model. Current libraries are narrow, something over 250 segments with emotion scaled in separate data file from soundbytes should be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

There are many datasets available out there, with different set-ups (no noise/ noisy) targeting various emotion classes (positive/negative, anger/happy/sad etc.) and covering various languages (Arabic, French, German, English etc.). Here are a few:

- [MELD](https://affective-meld.github.io/)
- [Emov-DB](https://mega.nz/#F!KBp32apT!gLIgyWf9iQ-yqnWFUFuUHg!mYwUnI4K)
- [RAVDESS](https://www.kaggle.com/uwrfkaggler/ravdess-emotional-speech-audio)
- [ANAD](https://www.kaggle.com/suso172/arabic-natural-audio-dataset)
- [MSP-IMPROV](https://ecs.utdallas.edu/research/researchlabs/msp-lab/MSP-Improv.html)
- [CREMA-D](https://github.com/CheyneyComputerScience/CREMA-D)
- [EMOVO](http://voice.fub.it/activities/corpora/emovo/index.html)
- [RECOLA](https://diuf.unifr.ch/main/diva/recola/download.html)

For more information, please refer to this list https://superkogito.github.io/SER-datasets/, that I maintain on GitHub: [SER-datasets](https://github.com/SuperKogito/SER-datasets). This list includes a small description of each dataset, its languages and the emotions classes included.